# Moved route from app.js to route.js and app no longer works

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my app.js file I had the code below and it worked as intended. I need to clean up my code, so I moved it to it's own route at routes/random and it no longer works because I get an error that states: "http://localhost:1337/random/1/1/testing 404 (Not Found)" and I am not sure why. My original code was in my app.js file when it was working was:

```
app.get('/random/:room/:userId/:message', function(req, res) {
    fs.appendFile(room.number.toString(), req.params.message, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error writing messages to file');
        };
        fs.readFile('./' + room.number, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.fileNotFound) {
                    return this.sendErrorMessage('can\'t find the file, you linked it incorrectly');
                }
                console.log('error reading message file');
            };

            if (req.params.userId == 1) {
                messages.user1.push(data);
            } else {
                messages.user2.push(data);
            };
            console.log(messages);
            res.send(data);
            fs.unlink(req.params.room, function(err) {
            });

        });
    });
});
```

---

the new code includes the following for app.js

---

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var random = require('./routes/random');

app.use('/random/', random);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('public/js'));
app.use(express.static('public/images'));
```

---

and after I moved it, the route code is:

---

```
var express = require ('express');
var fs = require ('fs');
var random = express.Router();

random.get('/random/:room/:userId/:message', function(req, res) {
    fs.appendFile(room.number.toString(), req.params.message, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error writing messages to file');
        };
        fs.readFile('./' + room.number, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.fileNotFound) {
                    return this.sendErrorMessage('can\'t find the file, you linked it incorrectly');
                }
                console.log('error reading message file');
            };

            if (req.params.userId == 1) {
                messages.user1.push(data);
            } else {
                messages.user2.push(data);
            };
            console.log(messages);
            res.send(data);
            fs.unlink(req.params.room, function(err) {
            });

        });
    });
});


module.exports = random;
```

Can anyone explain what I have done wrong that won't allow it to find the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are defining a route called random\random... in random.js,  delete first   random there,  because  middleware(app.use..) will direct all routes with /random to your router instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your router is handling a url that starts with `/random`, and you attach this to your app under the path `/random/`. Remove one or the other (preferebly, the one inside the router).

Comment: I am still doing something wrong. I change the path in my router to '/:room/:userId/:message' and it still is giving me the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it. Both comments above are correct, but it still was throwing errors due to my variables being undefined. I figured it out though so I am closing this question. Thank you both